# How can I take every 24 columns from a data frame and add them to the bottom of another data frame?

Tags: r

How can I adjust this loop so that for every 24 columns, it takes the columns and effectively `rbind()`s them to a new data frame?

I know that this is far from correct, but some guidance would be great.

The idea is that after the first loop, columns 1 - 24 (inclusive) would be transferred/copied into a new (empty) data frame (`new_df`), and then the second loop would take columns 25 - 48 and `rbind()` those values to `new_df`.

The reason is because I have wide data, of which each column represents an hour within a certain day.  I want to extract each day-long block and have it represented in a long format.

I currently have this:

```
rows <- 168

for(i in 1:rows){
  while (rows > 0) {
    day <- df[, 1:24]
    df <- rbind(df, day)
    rows <- rows - 1
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that it behaves in the way I have described?

Some sample data:

```
df <- structure(c("2018-08-05 01:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", 
" 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 02:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 03:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 04:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 05:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 06:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 07:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 08:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 09:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 10:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 11:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 12:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 13:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 14:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 15:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 16:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 17:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 18:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 19:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 20:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 21:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-05 22:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-05 23:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-06 00:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-06 01:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-06 02:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-06 03:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-06 04:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   4", " 6", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"NA", NA, "2018-08-06 05:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-06 06:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-06 07:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-06 08:00:00", 
"0", " 0", "   0", "   0", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA, NA, "2018-08-06 09:00:00", "1", " 6", "   0", "   1", " 0", 
"0", "2", "2", "0", "0", "0", NA, "0.0000000", "2018-08-06 10:00:00", 
"1", "48", " 774", " 754", " 5", "1", "2", "2", "0", "0", "1", 
"0.2", "0.3333333", "2018-08-06 11:00:00", "1", "13", " 322", 
"1423", " 7", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.142857142857143", 
NA, "2018-08-06 12:00:00", "2", " 2", "  51", "1672", " 3", "1", 
"2", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0.333333333333333", "0.0000000", "2018-08-06 13:00:00", 
"2", "60", "1377", " 324", "10", "3", "3", "3", "0", "0", "0", 
"0.3", "0.0000000", "2018-08-06 14:00:00", "2", "51", "1009", 
" 478", " 3", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.333333333333333", 
NA, "2018-08-06 15:00:00", "4", "60", "1196", " 292", " 7", "0", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "NA", "0.0000000", "2018-08-06 16:00:00", 
"3", "60", "1329", " 378", "15", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0.0666666666666667", NA, "2018-08-06 17:00:00", "2", "22", " 481", 
" 995", " 8", "2", "3", "3", "0", "0", "0", "0.25", "0.0000000", 
"2018-08-06 18:00:00", "1", "28", " 391", " 789", " 5", "2", 
"2", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0.4", "0.0000000", "2018-08-06 19:00:00", 
"1", "60", "1169", " 301", " 8", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"NA", NA, "2018-08-06 20:00:00", "1", "60", "2442", " 421", "33", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0.0303030303030303", "1.0000000", 
"2018-08-06 21:00:00", "1", " 1", "   9", "2474", " 0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-06 22:00:00", "0", 
" 0", "   0", "2353", " 1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "NA", 
NA, "2018-08-06 23:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", "1430", " 0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-07 00:00:00", "0", 
" 0", "   0", "1019", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, 
NA, "2018-08-07 01:00:00", "0", " 0", "   0", " 805", " 0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "2018-08-07 02:00:00", "0", 
" 0", "   0", " 673", " 0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, 
NA), .Dim = c(14L, 50L), .Dimnames = list(c("hour", "associate_count", 
"minutes_covered", "plugin_loads", "plugin_unloads", "plugin_opens", 
"chats_started", "claimed_chats", "completed_chats", "sales.number_of_orders", 
"sales.subtotal", "missed_chats", "pct_resulting_in_chat", "missed_pct"
), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
"34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", 
"45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50")))
```

Comment: Do you really want to do that? I think it makes more sense to convert it into a [tidy format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data) (each column is a variable, each row an observation) using something like this: `data.frame(t(df))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data in the long format and at a day level, I suggest transposing your dataframe and then using an aggregate function

```
new_df <- as.data.frame(t(df))  

#create the date column and only retain the date part
new_df$date <- format(as.Date(as.character(new_df$hour), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

#aggregation
library(dplyr)
agg_df <- new_df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(Tot_associate_count = sum(associate_count))
```

Add the rest of the columns in a similar fashion

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
#get number of expected 24-col dataframes
N <- ncol(df)/24

# create empty list to store these dataframes
mylist <- list(length = N)

#split data by groups of 24 columns
for(i in 1:N) {
    mylist[i] <- df[ , ((i-1)*24+1):(i*24)]
}

# rbind all 24-col dataframes together
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Lynbakr's point:

You could get everything in long format:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df2 <- data.frame(t(df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  gather(measurement_type, measurement, -hour) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(measurement), as.integer)

> head(df2)
                 hour measurement_type measurement
1 2018-08-05 01:00:00  associate_count           0
2 2018-08-05 02:00:00  associate_count           0
3 2018-08-05 03:00:00  associate_count           0
4 2018-08-05 04:00:00  associate_count           0
5 2018-08-05 05:00:00  associate_count           0
6 2018-08-05 06:00:00  associate_count           0
```

And if you'd really like to split it into different `data.frame`s for each, this returns a list of them:

```
df2 %>% 
  split(lubridate::day(.$hour))
```

This is assuming all measurements are numeric. If you like each measurement as its own column, or if they're not all numeric (e.g., there's a categorical variable), you could drop the `gather` call.